# Close button didn't appear

Tags: javascript

This is To Do list project.

CSS code is not mine, it's copied from w3schools. JS code is mine, but it's not working.

I have problem because close button didn't appear on list elements. I checked files and all is good. Also, I'm beginner (learning JS), so I don't know too much, I found this project on web and tried to do it.

If anyone can help, thanks.

```js
   

 // DODAVANJE DUGMETA ZA BRISANJE ZADATKA
let tasks = document.querySelectorAll(".li");

for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
  let span = document.createElement("span");
  let removeButton = document.innerText("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(removeButton);
  tasks[i].appendChild(span);
}

// TEKST UNESEN U INPUT POLJE
let input = document.querySelector('#inputText')

// FUNKCIJA KOJA DODAJE NOVI ZADATAK NA LISTU
function newTask() {
    let task = document.createElement('li'); // PROMENLJIVA TASK PREDSTAVLJA ZADATAK (LI)
    let inputText = input.value; // PROMENLJIVA INPUT TEXT PREDSTAVLJA TEKST KOJI JE UPISAN U INPUT POLJE

    task.innerText = inputText;
    input.value = ''; // BRISANJE STAROG TEKSTA IZ INPUT POLJA

    let list = document.querySelector('#list');

    list.appendChild(task)
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 250px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

ul li.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

ul li.checked::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 15px;
  width: 7px;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Clear floats after the header */
.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Style the input */
input {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* Style the "Add" button */
.addBtn {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.addBtn:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> To Do List </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="task-manager" class="header">
        <h2 style="margin:5px"> Lista zadataka </h2>
        <input type="text" id="inputText" placeholder=" Naziv zadatka ">
        <span onclick="newTask()" class="addBtn">Dodaj</span>
    </div>

    <ul id="list">

    </ul>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because your html doesn't have any `.li` elements

Comment: It's To do list project, in js file I have code that makes li elements on click

Comment: are you adding `<li>` elements or elements with `li` className? because you are searching for className `li` elements

Comment: Just edited post.

Comment: remove the dot from your queryselector. But that will not solve the issue, because the code that adds buttons runs before function that adds items executed, therefore there is no `li` elements exists yet.

Comment: Sorry, not working.

Comment: It's not working for the reason explained above. Why are you not adding close button together when creating an item?